# Generic FluentValidation Validator with a generic enum

Tags: c#, generics, enums, fluentvalidation

I have been experimenting with generics and tried writing a generic validator using a generic enum.

The setup is as following:

I have an interface:

```
public interface IHasProperties<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public IEnumerable<TEnum>? Properties { get; set; }
}
```

The following models:

```
public class Model<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> ModelWithProperties { get; set; }
}

public class ModelWithProperties : IHasProperties<Properties>
{
    public IEnumerable<Properties> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

An enum:

```
public enum Properties
{
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3
}
```

With this I want to create a generic 'properties' validator:

```
public class ModelPropertiesValidator<T, TEnum> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : IHasProperties<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public ModelPropertiesValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Properties).NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

But when I want to use it:

var validator = new ModelPropertiesValidator<Model, Properties>();

The following error pops up:

**The type 'Project.Models.Model<Project.Models.ModelWithProperties>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ModelPropertiesValidator<T, TEnum>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Project.Models.Model<Project.Models.ModelWithProperties>' to 'Project.Contracts.IHasProperties<Project.Types.Properties>'.**

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to:

```
var validator = new ModelPropertiesValidator<ModelWithProperties, Properties>();
```

Comment: I think your answer is definitely part of the solution but I still have to do the .First() call when I call Validate method. What I'd like to do is pass the Model holding the ModelWithProperties list there. Or validate all ModelWithProperties instead of only the first.  
  
`var validator = new ModelPropertiesValidator<ModelWithProperties, Properties>();
var result = validator.Validate(model.ModelWithProperties.First());`